# <a href = "./folder2">link to other folder</a> doesn't work on Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, directory, href

Say I'm in folder1 and want to enter folder2, which is inside folder1.

I found this solution:

`<a href="./folder2">link to folder2</a>`

This works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Google Chrome. For it to work in Chrome I needed to add /folder1 between the . and the /, like this:

`<a href="./folder1/folder2">link to folder2</a>`

And this doesn't work in Firefox.

Is there a way to make it work on both browsers?

---

**Solved:** Out of nowhere it decided to work on both browsers when I used the second option I mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean by "folder?" Are you talking about `file://` URLs?

Comment: What is your exact starting URL?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm in http://localhost/C:/folder/folder1/ and want to access folder2 which is inside folder1.

Comment: Leave off `./`. It's redundant.

Comment: I didn't work at all if I left out the `./`.

Comment: Does it work with `/folder2` (without period).

Comment: No, I tried that as well.

Comment: Doesn't `<a href="folder2/">link to folder2</a>` work?

Comment: `<a href="folder2/">link to folder2</a>` seems to work on Firefox, but not Chrome. I want it to work on both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link from the directory.
Some page:

```
<a href="/folder1">Go to folder 1</a>
```

Folder 1:

```
<a href="/folder1/folder2">Go to folder 2</a>
```

Folder 2:

```
<a href="/folder1">Go back/a>
```

The only other way I know of is to use javascript to take the url and add the current url to it

> Current Directory + Clicked Link

Comment: This seems to be working on both browsers, thank you!

**Edit:** It doesn't work unless I include the `C:` in the beginning. I noticed because when I tried opening an image in folder2, I couldn't, and then I noticed I was missing the `C:` in the path on the browser. Is there a way to make it work without including it?

Comment: This is because you are hosting the html on your pc. You have to go from the directory of your computer. EDIT: When you host your code it will automatically go from your domain. (http://www.example.com/)

Comment: If you go to file:///C:// in your browser, left click a link, copy the address and look at it. As you see it shows the entire link from the directory. The only other way to do this is with javascript.